# No sound on Asus Zenbook UM433D with Ubuntu 20.04.2.0

Tags: dual-boot, sound, live-usb, asus, amd-ryzen

Since March 2020 I have been trying Ubuntu on Asus Zenbook UM433D (family name) UM434DA-A5949T (more precise name, with 434 instead of 433...). I use "try ubuntu" with a USB key. I don't want to install Ubuntu if "try" does not work. The main problem is NO SOUND. I tried many versions, 18.04, 19.10, 20.04, 20.10 and today 20.04.2.0. I see many similar problems on the web: for years, people have been describing the same problem. Sometimes someone fixes it. Then the problem appears again with a new computer or a new version of Ubuntu. For example, following the link in the answer to "Asus Zenbook UM433D Ubuntu 19.04 no sound", I see that an update to the solution is proposed. Anyway, I cannot make a change and then reboot with the option "try". Also, UX has an Intel processor, while UM has an AMD Ryzen 3700U processor.

I have no sound from the internal speakers, and the internal microphone does not work. With Windows, everything is working. I copy some data:

Linux ubuntu 5.8.0-43-generic #49-20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP 5 feb 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

AlsaMixer v1.2.2
HD-Audio Generic
ATI R6xx HDMI
S/PDIF

Aptio, 2019, Bios Vendor American trends, version 302, GOP Version 2.5.0.0.0, EC Version FOPC1501.005, processor Info AMD Ryzen 7 3700 with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx 2300 MHz

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Linux ubuntu 5.8.0-43-generic #49-20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP 5 feb 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux This is not a Ubuntu version its a kernel version. From that I can see it must be 20.04 or 20.10 which is it?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS downloaded yesterday.

Comment: Same result with Ubuntu 21.04. No sound from the internal speakers, no sound from the headphones. The microphone does not work.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-asus-zenbook-15-ux534f-realtek-hd-audio-problem.27384/ from here:

1. disable fast boot in BIOS
2. disable fast boot in Windows
3. Shutdown (not restart)
4. boot into Linux

Comment: There was another more ugly solution, but this already worked for me

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I had fast boot already disabled in Windows. I just disabled it in the BIOS (same page as boot choices) and I could boot and hear the Ubuntu sound for the first time. This is a perfect solution to my problem.